# why does Xcode shows two different current branches

Tags: xcode

Xcode 14.2: what's up with this? I created the new (correct) branch from the command-line. Is there a problem? Is this an Xcode bug? Anybody else seeing this?

[image: wrong branch]

Comment: I've seen that on occasion. Restart Xcode. Though sometimes it will fix itself if you do anything in Xcode that causes it to refresh git status.